# multiple gradients in GIMP

Tags: gimp, gradient

I am struggling to get multiple gradients in GIMP as shown in this youtube video @2min 18seconds.

This idea is to have the background of my smaller/inset picture completely removed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYsQF93UR6w&t=104s

Every time I attempt a 2nd gradient, the first one is removed. I am using v2.10.36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, because I can't see your tool options settings, and I can't see what you are actually doing.

Check you have selected the "FG to Tansparent" gradient in the tool options, and obviously make sure you have the FG colour set to Black.

[image]

If you have one of the "FG to BG" gradients selected it will just over paint the one you created previously.

Alternatively, if you do have a "FG to BG" gradient selected in the Tool Options, and have Black FG and White BG colours selected, you could set the Gradient Tool Options to use a blending mode such as "Multiply". Then when you use the tool it will blend the two rather than over paint.

Other methods also exist for making a mask like this. You can paint directly on the layer mask with a very large soft edged brush (in black to hide, or in white to reveal), perhaps reduce the opacity for more control.

Comment: You were right. I had one of the "FG to BG" gradients selected. I switched to "FG to Tansparent" and can now do multi gradients. However, I notice that for the FG/inset/smaller picture, the border is still visible although very fine. Is there a way to remove it completely?

Comment: @shoggananna - paint it away with a large soft edged brush set to black. You can paint on a mask.